# Why is including a header only sometimes necessary?

Tags: c++, std, c++20

I'm new to C++ and I have this program (you'll notice it `#include`s `iostream` but nothing else):

```
// Prompt from https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/dynamically-allocating-arrays/
#include <iostream>
// #include <algorithm> // for std::sort()

int main() {
    int numNames{};
    std::cout << "How many names? ";
    std::cin >> numNames;

    std::string *nameList{ new std::string[static_cast<std::size_t>(numNames)]{} };

    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(10000, '\n');

    for (int count{ }; count < numNames; ++count) {
        std::string name{};
        std::cout << "Enter name #" << count + 1 << ": ";
        std::getline(std::cin, name);

        nameList[count] = name;
    }

    std::sort(nameList, nameList + numNames);

    std::cout << "\nHere's your list, sorted:" << '\n';

    for (int index{ }; index < numNames; ++index) {
        std::cout << "Name #" << index + 1 << ": " << nameList[index] << '\n';
    }

    delete[] nameList;
    nameList = nullptr;

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles and runs, even though `<string>`, `<algorithm>`, and `<cstddef>`, all of which are used (for `std::string`, `std::sort`, and `std::size_t`). However, if I remove `<iostream>` it doesn't. Why is this? Shouldn't using `std::string` or `sort` or `size_t` result in a compiler error?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: It seems that in your current implementation of the C++ standard library, the `iostream` header includes `string`, `algorithm`, and `cstddef`.  (Or maybe something like `iostream` includes `string` which includes `algorithm` which includes `cstddef`).  But you shouldn't rely on this being the case for all standard library implementations; in other words, while this code compiles on your box, it may not compile on someone else's box.

Comment: @0RR, I'm using clang on MacOS Big Sur.

Comment: @0x5453 That makes sense, thank you.

Comment: Omitting `<string>`, `<algorithm>`, or `<cstddef>` results in compiler errors on my machine for missing symbols.